# How do I split a 9x9 array into 9 3x3 components

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a 9x9 multidimensional array that represents a sudoku game. I need to break it into it's 9 3x3 many components. How would this be done? I have absolutely no idea where to begin, here.

```
game = [
[1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8],
[4, 9, 8, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 5],
[7, 5, 6, 3, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9],
[6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 8, 7, 9, 2],
[5, 2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 8, 4, 6],
[9, 8, 7, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 1],
[2, 1, 4, 9, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7],
[3, 6, 5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2, 4],
[8, 7, 9, 6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3]
]
```

Split into chunks, it becomes

```
chunk_1 = [
[1, 3, 2],
[4, 9, 8],
[7, 5, 6]
]

chunk_2 = [
[5, 7, 9],
[2, 6, 1],
[3, 8, 4]
]

...and so on
```

Comment: Like any other language, it's a matter of nested loops.  Start at 0, count to 2.  Then start at 3, count to 6, and so on.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I'm actually experimenting with a loop-de-loop function right now, but I know there's a much more efficient way of doing it since I know other people have done this in very few LOC. If a better solution isn't presented, and if my solution works, I'll just post that and mark it as closed.

Comment: I think you should post what you've got as part of the question.  If there are improvements to be made, that's where people will chime in.

Comment: @durbnpoisn, oh I'm still experimenting with it. The loop within a loop occurred to me after posting the question. If it works, I'll certainly post it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn : You can write Fortran in any language, it doesn't mean it's a good idea to do so with Ruby ;)

Comment: I sometimes forget how different an animal Ruby is.  But that's why I gave a generic comment rather than an answer I didn't have.;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was a fun exercise!

## Answer

```
game.each_slice(3).map{|stripe| stripe.transpose.each_slice(3).map{|chunk| chunk.transpose}}.flatten(1)
```

It would be cumbersome and not needed to define every `chunk_1, chunk_2, ...`.

If you want `chunk_2`, you can use `extract_chunks(game)[1]`

It outputs `[chunk_1, chunk_2, chunk_3, ..., chunk_9]`, so it's an Array of Arrays of Arrays :

```
1 3 2
4 9 8
7 5 6

5 7 9
2 6 1
3 8 4

4 6 8
3 7 5
2 1 9

6 4 3
5 2 1
...
```

You can define a method to check if this grid is valid (it is) :

```
def extract_chunks(game)
  game.each_slice(3).map{|stripe| stripe.transpose.each_slice(3).map{|chunk| chunk.transpose}}.flatten(1)
end

class Array # NOTE: Use refinements if you don't want to patch Array
  def has_nine_unique_elements?
    self.flatten(1).uniq.size == 9
  end
end

def valid?(game)
  game.has_nine_unique_elements? &&
  game.all?{|row| row.has_nine_unique_elements? } &&
  game.all?{|column| column.has_nine_unique_elements? } &&
  extract_chunks(game).all?{|chunk| chunk.has_nine_unique_elements? }
end

puts valid?(game) #=> true
```

## Theory

- The big grid can be [sliced](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) in 3 stripes, each containing 3 rows of 9 cells.
- The first stripe will contain chunk_1, chunk_2 and chunk_3.
- We need to cut the strip vertically into 3 chunks. To do so :

  - We [transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) the strip,
  - Cut it horizontally with [`each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice),
  - [transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) back again.
- We do the [same](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) for stripes #2 and #3.
- To avoid returning an Array of Stripes of Chunks of Rows of Cells, we use [`flatten(1)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) to remove one level and return an Array of Chunks of Rows of Cells. :)

Comment: Ofcourse! `each_slice`! I knew there was a Ruby way of doing it, I just knew there was!

Answer (score 5):

The method [Matrix#minor](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor) is tailor-made for this:

```
require 'matrix'

def sub3x3(game, i, j)
  Matrix[*game].minor(3*i, 3, 3*j, 3).to_a
end

chunk1 = sub3x3(game, 0, 0)
  #=> [[1, 3, 2], [4, 9, 8], [7, 5, 6]] 
chunk2 = sub3x3(game, 0, 1)
  #=> [[5, 7, 9], [2, 6, 1], [3, 8, 4]] 
chunk3 = sub3x3(game, 0, 2)
  #=> [[4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 5], [2, 1, 9]] 
chunk4 = sub3x3(game, 1, 0)
  #=> [[6, 4, 3], [5, 2, 1], [9, 8, 7]]
...
chunk9 = sub3x3(game, 2, 2)
  #=> [[6, 8, 7], [9, 2, 4], [1, 5, 3]]
```

Ruby has not concept of "rows" and "columns" of arrays. For convenience, therefore, I will refer to the 3x3 "subarray" of `game`, at offsets `i` and `j` (`i = 0,1,2`, `j = 0,1,2`), as the 3x3 submatrix of `m = Matrix[*game]` whose upper left value is at row offset `3*i` and column offset `3*j` of `m`, converted to an array.

This is relatively inefficient as a new matrix is created for the calculation of each "chunk". Considering the size of the array, this is not a problem, but rather than making that more efficient you really need to rethink the overall design. Creating nine local variables (rather than, say, an array of nine arrays) is not the way to go.

Here's a suggestion for checking the validity of `game` (that uses the method `sub3x3` above) once all the open cells have been filled. Note that I've used the [Wiki description of the game](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku), in which the only valid entries are the digits 1-9, and I have assumed the code enforces that requirement when players enter values into cells.

```
def invalid_vector_index(game)
  game.index { |vector| vector.uniq.size < 9 }
end

def sub3x3_invalid?(game, i, j)
  sub3x3(game, i, j).flatten.uniq.size < 9
end

def valid?(game)
  i = invalid_vector_index(game)
  return [:ROW_ERR, i] if i
  j = invalid_vector_index(game.transpose)
  return [:COL_ERR, j] if j
  m = Matrix[*game]
  (0..2).each do |i|
    (0..2).each do |j|
      return [:SUB_ERR, i, j] if sub3x3_invalid?(game, i, j)
    end
  end
  true
end

valid?(game)
  #=> true
```

Notice this either returns `true`, meaning `game` is valid, or an array that both signifies that the solution is not valid and contains information that can be used to inform the player of the reason.

Now try

```
game[5], game[6] = game[6], game[5]
```

so

```
game
  #=> [[1, 3, 2,   5, 7, 9,   4, 6, 8],
  #    [4, 9, 8,   2, 6, 1,   3, 7, 5],
  #    [7, 5, 6,   3, 8, 4,   2, 1, 9],

  #    [6, 4, 3,   1, 5, 8,   7, 9, 2],
  #    [5, 2, 1,   7, 9, 3,   8, 4, 6],
  #    [2, 1, 4,   9, 3, 5,   6, 8, 7],

  #    [9, 8, 7,   4, 2, 6,   5, 3, 1],
  #    [3, 6, 5,   8, 1, 7,   9, 2, 4],
  #    [8, 7, 9,   6, 4, 2,   1, 5, 3]] 

valid?(game)
  #=> [:SUB_ERR, 1, 0]
```

The rows and columns are obviously still valid, but this return value indicates that at least one 3x3 subarray is invalid and the array

```
[[6, 4, 3],
 [5, 2, 1],
 [2, 1, 4]]
```

was the first found to be invalid.

Comment: This takes the cake. I'm going to look into this now.

Comment: Also, since you're checking the validity, you must ensure that all rows and columns add up to 45.

Comment: ....that didn't even occur to me! Off-topic but how long have you been coding? I'm only asking since I've been using Ruby for almost a year now and while I'm fairly proficient, I'm trying to calculate the time i have left until I reach Godlike status in general coding.

Comment: @amingilani Checking that all 9 values are unique makes it possible to have a sudoku with `a,b,c,...` instead of `1,2,3`. Plus I'm not sure that `sum==45` is enough for a Sudoku to be valid.

Comment: @EricDuminil it is if you're playing a standard 9x9 grid, but you're right, checking for uniqueness is a much better approach.

Comment: @amingilani : A grid full of 5's would have a sum of 45 everywhere.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `sub3x3` doesn't return the correct chunk, so `valid?` returns a false negative on the provided example. On top of that, `valid?` doesn't use enough tests and can also return false positives.

Comment: @EricDuminil, I'll look into that in awhile. I was in a rush when I posted the answer so didn't do thorough testing, but `valid?` does check each row, each column and each of the nine 3x3's.

Comment: @EricDuminil, my bad, it was very late in my timezone when i read it and didn't check it until now. For now, I'm switching the correct answer back to yours for completeness' sake.

Comment: @Eric, actually, there were several errors. I hope I've corrected all of them. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @amingilani, assuming your "Godlike" question was addressed to me, I began tinkering with Ruby about six years ago, well after I retired from the labour force. I think [Matz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto) is the only Rubiest with "Godlike status". He released the first version of Ruby 21 years ago this month. There are many others, however, who have "proficient" status.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : your `valid?` still doesn't check enough. Hint : there are an infinity of grids for which your method returns a false positive.

Comment: @Eric, I'm at a loss. The only requirements for a [Soduko](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) solution to be valid are that each row, column and 3x3 grid contain all of the numbers 1-9. I am of course assuming that the code demands that players enter a number between 1 and 9 (and nothing else) in each open cell of the grid and that `valid?` is not applied until entries have been made for all open cells. What am I missing?

Comment: Sudoku can be filled with letters, colors and basically any object (http://www.tomphillips.co.uk/images/stories/News/colour_sudoku-blog.jpg). So I'd say it's important that exactly 9 objects are used for the whole grid. `(1..9).map{(1..9).map{Object.new}}` is a valid grid with your code.

Comment: @Eric, as I indicated in my comment above, I've used the Wiki description of the game, in which the only valid entries are the digits 1-9, and have assumed the code enforces that requirement when players enter values into cells. I'll edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that generates a single 3X3 chunk from a given index. since the sudoku board is of length 9, that will produce 9 3X3 chunks for you. see below.

```
#steps
#you'll loop through each index of the board
#to get the x value
#you divide the index by 3 and multiply by 3
#to get the y value
#you divide the index by 3, take remainder and multiply by 3
#for each x value, you can get 3 y values
#this will give you a single 3X3 box from one index so

def three_by3(index, sudoku)
  #to get x value
  x=(index/3)*3
  #to get y value
  y=(index%3)*3
  (x...x+3).each_with_object([]) do |x,arr|
    (y...y+3).each do |y|
      arr<<sudoku[x][y]
    end
  end
end
sudoku = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
          [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2],
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
          [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2],
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
          [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]]

p (0...sudoku.length).map {|i| three_by3(i,sudoku)}
#output:
#[[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5], 
# [4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8], 
# [7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 1, 9, 1, 2], 
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5], 
# [4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8], 
# [7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 1, 9, 1, 2], 
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5], 
# [4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8], 
# [7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 1, 9, 1, 2]]
```